# How to keep cursor input from spamming hover element?

Tags: html, css

I have a centered three-part logo at the top of a page that I want to have one part slide to the left for one half and the other half to the right on mouse hover. I have accomplished that, however, it animates on every hover input and makes for a rather poor look. I would like know if it's possible to make the logo piece animate on only one mouse hover, and have it stay there until the mouse leaves the area of the logo piece's original position.

```css
/* Forward-Logo-P2 */

.hvr-forward {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.75;
  transition-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-forward:hover,
.hvr-forward:focus,
.hvr-forward:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
  transform: translateX(400px);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


/* Backward-Logo-P1 */

.hvr-backward {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.75s;
  transition-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-backward:hover,
.hvr-backward:focus,
.hvr-backward:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
  transform: translateX(-400px);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img class="logo hvr-backward" border="0" src="../images/logo-p1.png">

  <img class="logo" border="0" src="../images/logo-p3.png">

  <img class="logo hvr-forward" border="0" src="../images/logo-p2.png">
</div>
```

Comment: The reason for the spastic movement is because when you hover, it moves the element - now you're not hovered anymore, so it moves it back - now you are hovered again so it moves the element - now you're not hovered anymore, so it moves it back - now you are hovered again so it moves the element ENDLESS LOOP.  Refactor your code to move something you are not hovering on. Perhaps you can add some additional DIVs to isolate what is hovered over from what is moved. Don't be concerned about adding several other divs... if it solves your problem, it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling this to many times by grouping focus, active and hover to perform the same function hence the flashing. Just do it on hover, or active so it is done only on click but goes back once you release the click.

```
.hvr-forward:hover,
.hvr-forward:focus,
.hvr-forward:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
  transform: translateX(400px);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

chnage to:

```
.hvr-forward:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
  transform: translateX(400px);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

script may allow you to do something more bespoke